# Win32 program compiler errors in class definition file

Tags: c++, winapi, compiler-errors

I am trying to Compile in Visual C++ and just added this config file loader/parser to my project.  For some ever function defined in class CProfileData is receiving at least one of two errors:

```
missing type specifier - int assumed.
syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
```

When obviously this should just be a referenced string

```
#ifdef UVSS_EXPORTS
#define UVSS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define UVSS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


class CProfileData
{

public:
    UVSS_API CProfileData(){};
    UVSS_API CProfileData(const string& profileFile);
    UVSS_API ~CProfileData(void);

    UVSS_API bool GetVariable( const string& sectionName, const string& variableName, string& valueRet );
    UVSS_API bool GetSection( const string& sectionName, SECTION_MAP **pMapRet );
    UVSS_API bool GetVariableW( const string& sectionName, const string& variableName, wstring& valueRet );
    UVSS_API bool GetVariableInt( const string& sectionName, const string& variableName, int *pIntRet );

private:
    void ToLower( string& str );
    void TrimWhitespace( string& str);   
    bool IsComment( const string& str );
    bool IsSection( const string& str, string& secName );
    bool IsVariable( const string& str, string& name, string& value );

    PROFILE_MAP         m_mapProfile;

};
```

Comment: Have you tried `#include <string>`? and then you will need to make thos string be `std::string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include `<string>`:

```
#include <string>
```

And write `std::string` wherever you've written `string`.

Its not a good idea to do either of the following in a *header* file:

```
using namespace std; //avoid doing this
using std::string;   //avoid doing this as well
```

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that these two lines appear before including this header:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
```

Comment: -1 This is very bad advice.  The include should be *in* this header, not in the file including it.  And in a header, unless there are project wide conventions stating otherwise, it's probably best to avoid the `using`, and specify `std::string` completely at each use.

Comment: I agree, @James, with your advice. But, I inferred from @Joe's request that this header was an external dependency and he wasn't able to edit it.